# Inquiry about a branch of study. (possibly bandit)

Tags: probability-theory

I'm working on the problem below and I was wondering if anyone came across this kind of problem before? I'm not sure which field of studies I should look into to solve the problem.

Each period, a firm is faced with the problem,

$\pi _t = a x^2 _t$

where a is unknown and t=1, ..., n.

They only observe their total profit after the game finishes. (at t = n+1)
instead, they observe a signal, z, after each period which is given by

$z_t$ ~ $N(a, b/x_t^2)$

and x is closed and bounded, $x \in [0, \bar{x} ]$

The firm chooses x to maximise its profit

What would be the optimal path of x?

The closest branch of studies I can think of is bandit problems. But in this case, each arm has a related reward distribution and information gained for one arm (eg. x=2 in period 1) can be exploited using the other arm. So i'm not sure if my problem is a simplification of the bandit problem or an another branch of study.

Any recommendation to literatures I can look into would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks for reading this long inquiry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it stands, I don't think your problem is entirely complete. The firm doesn't really face any trade-off: they can maximize their expected sum of profits by simply choosing $x_t=\bar{x}$. Also, I'm not sure if you're assuming that $a$ and $b$ are variables or whether they're unknown to the firm.

However, what you're asking sounds a lot like a dynamic optimization problem (one that is often seen in macroeconomics). If I reformulate the problem as follows I think you should get a better idea of how to go about solving it.

Suppose a risk neutral firm faces the following problem:
$$ \max_{x_t} \sum_{t=0}^{T-1} E[\pi_{t+1}] $$
Subject to $k_{t+1}=k_t-x_t+z_{t+1}$, $k_0>0$ is given, $x_t,k_t\ge 0$ and
$$ \pi_{t+1} = z_{t+1} \sim N(a,b/x_t^2) $$
In words: the firm maximizes its expected profits over the length of the game by making variance reducing investments; the firm observes a realization of its 'winnings' only after it has invested, and is endowed with an initial 'kitty' from which to spend.

It's pretty straightforward to go about solving it (although no guarantee a closed form solution exists). I'd have a go at setting up the Lagrangian:
$$ \max_{x_t,k_{t+1}} \mathcal{L} = \sum_{t=0}^{T-1} \left[ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} z_{t+1} \frac{x_t}{
\sqrt{b}} \phi\left(\frac{z_{t+1}-a}{b/x_t^2}\right) dz_{t+1} + \lambda_t \left(k_t-x_t+z_{t+1}-k_{t+1}\right) \right] $$
Where $\phi()$ is the standard normal pdf.

There are a couple of alternative approaches to this kind of problem. You could think about using dynamic programming (i.e., setting up a Bellman equation) and/or backward induction from the last period.

Enjoy!

Comment: Hi Alan, Thank you so much for your answer. The reason that it may be a trade off is because a is an unknown number that can be negative or positive. also, b is a known positive constant.
uhm, just a few questions on your solution. I'm sorry but I didn't quite follow the line.
$\pi _t+1 = z_{t+1}$.
could you explain this part for me please?
Thank you!

Comment: I reckon it'd be much more complicated, but you could go about specifying a stochastic $a$ (and its probability distribution). As it stands if $z$ is drawn from a normal distribution there will still be a chance it is negative.

Basically for $\pi_{t+1}=z_{t+1}$ I am assuming that returns (profits) are stochastic, following a normal distribution with mean $a$ and variance $b/x_{t}^2$. The idea is there are two phases - the firm picks $x_t$ this period and observes $\pi_{t+1}=z_{t+1}$ next period.

Comment: yeh, I've actually solved the problem that way using Bayesian updating by setting a prior distribution on a for the two-period model. But it gets very messy beyond two-period model so i've been trying to find another approach to make the model an infinite horizon. Uhm jst with your use of $k _{t+1}$, what is the intuition behind it? sorry for asking you to explain everything... math is not my expertise..

Comment: No problem. Take gambling as the example - you bring an initial fixed amount of money to the casino $k_0$ and gamble $x_0$. The first period you observe your winnings $z_1$ and gamble again $x_1$. Your total stock of money available to gamble is now: $k_1=k_0+z_1-x_0$ (i.e., your initial money minus the amount you gambled plus your winnings this period). Forcing this kind of a 'budget restriction' ensures that it isn't optimal to just set $x_t=\bar{x}$ (since even if $a<0$ it would still be optimal to spend the max each period).